# Writing a function that accepts any two numbers (any real or any integer)

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I have a function that accepts two numbers and I don't care if they are integers or real or 32bits or 64bits.  For the example below, I just write it as a simple multiplication.  In Fortran 90 you could do this with an interface block, but you'd have to write 16 (!) functions if you wanted to cover all the possible interactions of multiplying two numbers, each of which could be int32, int64, real32, or real64.

With Fortran 2003 you have some other options like `class(*)` for polymorphism and I found one way to do this by simply converting all the inputs to reals, before multiplying:

```
! compiled on linux with gfortran 4.8.5

program main

   integer,   target :: i = 2
   real(4),   target :: x = 2.0
   real(8),   target :: y = 2.0
   character, target :: c = 'a'

   print *, multiply(i,x)
   print *, multiply(x,i)
   print *, multiply(i,i)
   print *, multiply(y,y) 
   print *, multiply(c,c)

contains

function multiply(p,q)

   real :: multiply
   class(*) :: p, q

   real :: r, s

   r = 0.0 ; s = 0.0

   select type(p)

      type is (integer(4)) ; r = p
      type is (integer(8)) ; r = p
      type is (real(4)) ;    r = p
      type is (real(8)) ;    r = p

      class default ; print *, "p is not a real or int"

   end select

   select type(q)

      type is (integer(4)) ; s = q
      type is (integer(8)) ; s = q
      type is (real(4)) ;    s = q
      type is (real(8)) ;    s = q

      class default ; print *, "q is not a real or int"

   end select

   multiply = r * s

end function multiply

end program main
```

This seems like an improvement.  At least the amount of code here is linear in the number of types rather than quadratic, but I wonder if there is still a better way to do this?  As you can see I still have to write the `select type` code twice, changing 'r' to 's' and 'p' to 'q'.

I tried to convert the select type blocks into a function but couldn't get that to work.  But I am interested in any and all alternatives that can further improve on this.  It seems like this would be a common problem but I so far haven't found any general approach that is better than this.

**Edit to add:**  Apparently there are plans to improve Fortran w.r.t. this issue in the future as noted in the comment by @SteveLionel.  @roygvib further provides a link to a specific proposal which also does a nice job of explaining the issue:  https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/13/13-236.txt

Comment: You can use `type is (real(4))` and `type is (real(8))` or `real32` and `real64` instead of `4` and `8` if you use `use iso_fortran_env`.

Comment: @AboAmmar Thanks! I have updated the question to reflect this suggestion.

Comment: This is a type of problem that can be solved with generic programming. The Fortran standard doesn't have good features for that, but the committee has started work on developing such for a future revision to the standard.

Comment: @SteveLionel  Thanks, I look forward to that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution for generics, but for "converting the select type blocks into a function", the following code seems to work (which might be useful if some nontrivial conversion is included (?)).

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer      :: i = 2
    real*4       :: x = 2.0
    real*8       :: y = 2.0
    character(3) :: c = 'abc'

    print *, multiply( i, x )
    print *, multiply( x, i )
    print *, multiply( i, i )
    print *, multiply( y, y )
    print *, multiply( c, c )

contains

function toreal( x ) result( y )
    class(*) :: x
    real :: y

    select type( x )
        type is (integer)      ; y = x
        type is (real(4))      ; y = x
        type is (real(8))      ; y = x
        type is (character(*)) ; y = len(x)
        class default          ; stop "no match for x"
    endselect
end

function multiply( p, q ) result( ans )
    class(*) :: p, q
    real :: ans
    ans = toreal( p ) * toreal( q )
end

end program

! gfortran-8 test.f90 && ./a.out
   4.00000000    
   4.00000000    
   4.00000000    
   4.00000000    
   9.00000000
```

Another approach may be just converting the actual arguments to reals (although it may not be useful for more practical purposes...)

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer   :: i = 2
    real*4    :: x = 2.0
    real*8    :: y = 2.0
    character :: c = 'a'

    print *, multiply( real(i), real(x) )
    print *, multiply( real(x), real(i) )
    print *, multiply( real(i), real(i) )
    print *, multiply( real(y), real(y) )
    ! print *, multiply( real(c), real(c) )  ! error

contains

function multiply( p, q ) result( ans )
    real :: p, q
    real :: ans
    ans = p * q
end

end program
```

Comment: Yes, this is very nice!  I tried to do something fairly similar but this is more elegant (not to mention that mine wouldn't actually compile ;-)  The second approach (just wrapping in real()) is our current approach but I think automating this via something approximating Julia's multiple dispatch is generally the better way, when feasible.

Comment: And how do you preserve the precision of `real64` if you convert every thing to `real32` like this?

Comment: But one possible issue is that select type may be pretty slow (though it may also depend on compilers + options..). For example, if I use the above multiply() many times (say 5 * 10^8), gfortran-8 -O2 takes 2.8 sec, while a statically overloaded version of toreal() (defined via an interface block) takes only 1.1 sec. So it may be better to avoid it for "hot" parts...

Comment: @AboAmmar I actually compile with default reals at 64bits, so not an issue IMO and of course can explicitly use real64 instead of real32 or default real in the conversion

Comment: @roygvib Good point, I figured that would be the case, but actually the slowdown you cite above is fine for my use case relative to the conciseness and convenience gained. But I can see that it would be worth it for other use cases, and if I'm thinking about this correctly, you'd only have to make the `toreal` function manageably larger (i.e. linear, not quadratic, increase in the amount of number types) and not touch the `multiply` function.  Might be worth writing out as a new answer or adding to your existing answer if you are so inclined...

Comment: @JohnE Yeah, I agree that the overhead can be small (or even negligible) in various situations (and not important as compared to convenience etc). RE multiple dispatch, it looks interesting but I've never seen an attempt to "emulate" it in Fortran... (e.g. [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#Examples_of_emulating_multiple_dispatch)) Using select type in a nested way (and so selecting dynamic types for multiple dummy arguments) might have some interesting usage (though not sure atm)

Comment: There seems to be an old proposal for this (in 2013), but no idea about the current status... but https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/13/13-236.txt

Comment: @roygvib FYI, I wrote out an answer elaborating on your timing comment above and to explicitly show the interface block code.  Feel free to edit that or comment on it, especially if you code the interface block method in a significantly different way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate approach using a statically overloaded function via an interface block as implicitly referred to in my question and @roygvib's answer.  (I figured it makes sense to have this written explicitly, especially if it someone can improve on it.)

Two advantages of the interface block method are:

- It's approximately 3x faster (as @roygvib also found, although I
  don't know exactly how he wrote the function)
- It only requires Fortran 90 (not Fortran 2003)

The main disadvantage is that you have to write the function multiple times.  As noted in the question, in this example you'd have to write the multiplication function 16 times, to handle all combos of 32 & 64 bit reals and ints.  It's not that terrible here, with the function being a single line of code, but you can easily see that this is more serious for many realistic use cases.

Below is the code I used to test the interface block method.  To keep it relatively concise, I tested only the 4 permutations of 32 bit reals and ints.  I re-used the main program to also test the @roygvib code.  On my 2015 macbook, it took about 16 seconds (interface block) vs 48 seconds (class(*) method).

Module:

```
module mult_mod

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: i4 => int32, r4 => real32

interface mult
   module procedure mult_real4_real4
   module procedure mult_int4_real4
   module procedure mult_real4_int4
   module procedure mult_int4_int4
end interface mult

contains

function mult_real4_real4( p, q ) result( ans )
    real(r4) :: p, q
    real(r4) :: ans
    ans = p * q
end function mult_real4_real4

function mult_int4_real4( p, q ) result( ans )
    integer(i4) :: p
    real(r4)    :: q
    real(r4) :: ans
    ans = p * q
end function mult_int4_real4

function mult_real4_int4( p, q ) result( ans )
    real(r4)    :: p
    integer(i4) :: q
    real(r4) :: ans
    ans = p * q
end function mult_real4_int4

function mult_int4_int4( p, q ) result( ans )
    integer(i4) :: p, q
    real(r4) :: ans
    ans = p * q
end function mult_int4_int4

end module mult_mod
```

Program:

```
program main

    use mult_mod

    integer(i4) :: i = 2
    real(r4)    :: x = 2.0

    integer(i4) :: i_end = 1e9
    real(r4)    :: result

    do j = 1, i_end

        result = mult( x, x )
        result = mult( x, i )
        result = mult( i, x )
        result = mult( i, i )

    end do

end program main
```

Comment: @jbdv  OK, I just re-read the linked Q&A more closely and see your point.  I'm just going to delete the comment and figure folks know the specifics of declaring reals and integers with whatever compiler they are using  ;-)  Feel free to edit again and I'll approve or apply whatever you want to do as I can see that you know what you are talking about