# Generalizing your operation for a specific declared type in Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, generic-programming, structure-of-arrays

I have a Structure of arrays using the declared type in Fortran

e.g.

```
 type t_data 

    integer :: N
    real, allocatable :: x(:)
    real, allocatable :: z(:)      
    real, allocatable :: y(:)

    contains 

    procedure :: copy
    procedure :: SWAP 
    procedure :: copy_element

 end type 

 ! constructor 
 interface t_data
    module procedure constructor 
 end interface  

 contains 

 subroutine copy(this, old) 
    class(t_data), intent(inout)    :: this
    type(t_data), intent(in)        :: old
    do i = 1, old% N
       this% x(i) = old% x(i) 
       etc .. 
    end do
 end subroutine 

 subroutine copy(this, old) 
    class(t_data), intent(inout)    :: this
    type(t_data), intent(in)        :: old
    do i = 1, old% N
       this% x(i) = old% x(i) 
       etc .. 
    end do
 end subroutine 

 function constructor(size_) 
    integer, intent(in) :: size_ 
    type(t_data), :: constructor
    allocate(constructor% x(size_)) 
    allocate(constructor% y(size_) ) 
    ! etc 
 end function 

 subroutine swap(this, from, i1,i2) 
    class(t_particle_data), intent(inout) :: this
    type(t_particle_data), intent(in)    :: from
    integer, intent(in)                  :: i1, i2

    this% x(i1) = from% x(i2) 
    ! etc 
 end subroutine
```

These are a set of examples of procedures that need to do same operations on all arrays of the declared type `t_data`. My question is how to make it more maintainable to tackle the situation when we for example later want to add a new component to the declared type. 
Currently, when I add a new array to my `t_data`, I need to go through all those procedures, constructors, deconstructors, and add the component.

I am asking if there is a way to make this more easier.

**MY APPLICATION**

Please note that these data type is used for particle simulation. Initially I allocate t_data with a large number. However, later during my simulation I might need more particles. Hence, I allocate a new t_data with more memory and copy over the old `t_data` up to its old size.

```
   subroutine NEW_ALLOC(new, old)
   type(t_data), intent(out) :: new  
   type(t_data), intent(inout) :: old  

   nsize = old% N * 2 ! allocate twice the old size 

   new = T_DATA(nsize) 
   call new% copy(old) 
   !DEALLCOte OLD
   end subroutine
```

Does anybody has/is it possible to make this in a more clever way. I do not mind mixing this with C/C++?

Comment: What does the `copy` subroutine do that is different from intrinsic assignment?  Why is it type bound?  Why use a loop to do array assignment?  How does moving to an array of structures make things easier?  Are you asking "How do I apply some operation consistently to all components of a derived type?"

Comment: @IanH, first question: no difference, however, in my case I am allocating with more elements than needed in the beginning of my simulation. During the sim, I sometimes require more elements, hence, I allocate a data type with more elements, and then do copy only up to the size of “old” data.    Second quest: does not have to. Third ques: i think from my description you would know why it now makes it easier. For you last question. Then, Yes please this is EXACTLY what I am asking. Please guide me if you have an idea

Comment: @highperformancemark, please can you explain further

Comment: Please notice I had an error in my example, the loop should go from 1 to old% N since we are only copying the old elements to the new (this). Now, the new type (this) would have an N which is larger than old% N, that is why my example would have been an error

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark   Can you please have a look at my revised thread

Comment: @IanH Can you please have a look at my revised thread

Comment: " My question is how to make it more maintainable to tackle the situation when we for example later want to add a new component to the derived type. Currently, when I add a new array to my t_data, I need to go through all those procedures, constructors, deconstructors, and add the new component manually "

Comment: Not sure if this is directly relevant, but here's a question I asked about making functions that can accept arbitrary intrinsic types, and is probably somewhat extensible to derived types:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792982/writing-a-function-that-accepts-any-two-numbers-any-real-or-any-integer

Comment: Perhaps this gist would be helpful (note this is the first of 2 parts):  https://gist.github.com/n-s-k/522f2669979ed6d0582b8e80cf6c95fd

Comment: If an array of structures makes the coding much simpler (than a structure of arrays), it may still be an option? (given that the performance is not too different.) Fortran can also access scalar components as mystructs(:) % x etc, which can be passed to other routines as a usual assumed-shape array.

Comment: I do actually have an example of the what you suggest @roygvib. I can only say that the performance difference is too different. Especially when I exploit vectorisation.

Comment: FYI, [this Intel forum page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/285396) seems to be discussing performance overhead using SOA vs AOS (with vectorization). I guess there will also be a hybrid (or intermediate) "several AOS's in a struct" approach also.

Comment: Other random ideas might be...: (1) write initializer routines carefully so that all the component types are updated automatically (e.g. by receiving an old object); (2) prepare a separate "manager" variable (e.g. an array of array pointers, X) that point to the fields of SOA, then pass this array to a desired routine to perform a uniform job on X(i) % arr_ptr(:); (3) increase or decrease the data size in-place (rather than copying the entire objects) e.g. by allocating somewhat larger component arrays from the beginning, etc...

Answer (score 3):

*My question is how to make it more maintainable to tackle the situation when we for example later want to add a new component to the declared type.*

Here's how I would tackle the situation, and how many Fortran programmers have tackled the situation.  I don't see the compelling need to have a derived type containing 3 arrays of coordinates, and approaching the problem that way does, as OP fears, require that adding another dimension to the problem requires code revision, such as adding a member array `real, allocatable :: w(:)` to `t_data` and recoding all the type-bound procedures operating on the type.

So drop that approach in favour of

```
TYPE t_data
   REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: elements
END TYPE t_data
```

let's have a couple of instances for exposition

```
TYPE(t_data) :: t1 ,t2, t3
```

and we can allocate the `elements` member of any of these this way

```
ALLOCATE(t1%elements(3,10))
```

which could just as easily be

```
ALLOCATE(t1%elements(6,100))
```

or whatever you wish.  This has the advantage over the original derived type design that the dimensions of `elements` can be determined at run-time.  It also makes it difficult to have different lengths for each of the coordinate arrays.

Now, copying `t1` is as simple as

```
t2 = t1
```

Modern Fortran even takes care of automatically allocating the `elements` of `t2`.  So I don't see any need for defining procedures for copying whole instances of `t_data`.  As for swapping data around, slicing and dicing, this is as simple as

```
t2%elements(1,:) = t1%elements(2,:)
```

even

```
t2%elements(1,:) = t1%elements(1,6:1:-1)
```

or

```
t2%elements(1,:) = t1%elements(1,[1,3,5,2,4,6])
```

It should be obvious how to wrap these into a `swap` routine.  But if not, ask another question.

Next, to the point about needing to allocate more space for elements during execution.  First a temporary array

```
REAL, DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: temp
```

then a little code like this, to double the size of `elements`.

```
ALLOCATE(temp(3,2*n))
temp(:,1:n) = t2%elements(:,1:n)
CALL MOVE_ALLOC(to=t2%elements,from=temp)
```

Again, you might care to wrap this into a procedure and if you need help doing that, ask for it.

Finally, the lesson of all this is not to share how *I* would program the problem, but to share the idea to *program **in** Fortran*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now my example is obviously simplified. But generally speaking my code is thousands of line with many objects for different parts. This object in particular literally contains more than 20 variables, and while this might be a good way to workaround it for certain limited cases, I honestly dont think it does with my application. 

Imagine having 20 components of my derived type, then I would need t1 to t20

Comment: Sadly I can only answer the question you ask so I'm not surprised that my answer is too simple for your real case.

Comment: With all due respect,  You solution moves this problem from having to handle many components in a procedure to handle many declared types. The whole point of this was how to handle the issue when we might want to create extra components to our type. This solution here would incur  extra declared type `t4`,`t5` that needs to be incorporated in the various routines. I get your point, which I also credited, however, I think it is quite fair to say that this does not tackle the problem that is being presented.

Comment: Well, as I wrote earlier, I really don't understand your question so it's no surprise my 'answer' is useless to you !